# How should I implement switching between multiple screen-pages correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, containers

I have layout for my content_page. I need container component, that could contain many content_pages and move between them with animation. Animation should be responsive (react on touch). When I press and move to side, visible content_page should move. Next page should be below current (like in stack).

**So is there existing approach, or should i implement it by myself?
Should i use fragments or it would be enough only with views?**

Note1. ViewPager can't be used because it pushes one page with another, and I need overlapping effect.

Note2. ViewFlipper can't be used because it shows only one view in time, and I need both for a moment, when I drag and move view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use ViewPager after all. Check out [this](https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms) library. Install demo and check "StackTranformer" transition. If I understood correctly, this should be exacly what you want.

Comment: Yes! There is StackTransformer. Thank you!